# the_excerpt(); tag not working

Tags: theme-development, excerpt

I am having a problem with the `the_excerpt();` tag which I am using in my own theme in the index.php and archive.php files. The code is below:

index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section class="center-column">
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <!--<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>-->
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <header>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <div class="post-date"><?php the_time(get_option( 'date_format' )); ?></div>
        </header>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <footer class="post-footer">
            <div class="categories">Posted in: <?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
            <div class="tags">Tags: <?php the_tags(); ?></div>
        </footer>
    </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <section class="post-navigation">
        <div class="alignleft">
            <?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="alignright">
            <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?>
        </div>
    </section>
<?php else : ?>
    <article>
        <h3>Not Found</h3>
        <p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that is not available</p>
    </article>
<?php endif; ?>
</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

archive.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section class="center-column">
    <!-- Archive Heading -->
    <section>
        <h3 id='archive-heading'>
            <?php if (is_category()) { ?>
            Archive for the '<?php single_cat_title(); ?>' Category
            <?php } elseif (is_tag()) { ?>
            Posts Tagged '<?php single_tag_title(); ?>'
            <?php } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
            Archive for <?php echo get_the_date('F Y'); ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </h3>
    </section>
    <!-- End Archive Heading -->

    <!-- Post Excerpt -->
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <header>
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="post-date"><?php the_time(get_option( 'date_format' )); ?></div>
                </header>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <footer>
                    <div class="categories">Posted in:
                        <?php the_category(', '); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tags">Tags:
                        <?php the_tags(); ?>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Sorry for the long pieces of code.

I am not sure exactly where the problem lies and would be grateful for any help you can provide.

Many thanks,
nav

Comment: So what's the actual problem? Excerpt not showing?

Comment: are you sure the page you're viewing is actually using the templates you think it's using, that could explain it. Personally I add `echo "index.php";` at the top or bottom of the index.php and same with other templates during development just so I can be sure.

Comment: Are you running any plugins?

Comment: @One Trick Pony: yes excerpt is not showing only title

Comment: @byronyasgur: I have added index.php and it is showing.@m0r7if3r: I am using eight plugins. The pity is that the excerpt shows on my local development machine running the same theme and plugins but not on the actual website. Should I look at any other files?

Comment: Can you post a live link? (Also: please ensure that you're using both `body_class()` and `post_class()`, as they might aid in troubleshooting.

Comment: @Chip Bennett: The live link is [here](http://swanlotus.com/blog). I am using both body_class and post_class in my templates and the excerpts appear on localhost but not on the live site.

Comment: Two questions: **1)** What do you have set as "page for posts" and "front page" in **Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading**? And **2)** Do you have a `home.php` template file defined? Your body classes aren't outputting properly on the URL you linked, but they *are* outputting properly on your front page, and on your single blog post.

Comment: @Chip Bennett: My front page is Home and my page for posts is Blog as on navigation bar. I do not have a home.php template defined. Regarding the body class I am unclear as what may be wrong with it on the Blog page shown from the nav bar.

Comment: How did you migrate the site from dev to production?

Comment: I tar gzipped my theme directory and uploaded it to the public_html/wp-content/themes directory on my server's wordpress install. Of course the .htaccess files are different. The content files and plugins are identical.

Comment: Swapping `the_excerpt()` with `the_content()` shows the full content as expected.

Comment: A shot in the dark here. I wonder if the excerpt itself might be the problem. Could you have written a manual excerpt on the actual posts which has no characters in it? (not even sure if that's possible) Another thing to do is to search your functions file for `excerpt_length` in case it's been filtered to 0 or something like that.

Comment: @byronyasgur: I did a grep on the theme directory and there are no manual excerpt and excerpt_length has been commented out. I have also reinstalled WordPress on the live site and re-uploaded my theme and I still have the same problem.

Comment: At this stage since you now have a fresh wordpress installation personally I'd create a copy of the theme and rename it (in style.css). Then strip that down to just two files, essential stylesheet and the index.php template which would have the simplest possible loop in it as the_excerpt() only works inside the loop. Activate that theme in appearance-themes. Last make sure no plugins are active. It really should work at that point and from there you could start adding in the bits you removed till it breaks and you know the problem then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your help, especially @byronyasgur for your last suggestion. It helped me fix it.

I was using markdown as the input format for the content, and the first line was HTML comment which was not followed by a blank line. Adding a blank line fixed it.

Summary: The absence of this line caused the excerpt to be null. This blnak line did exist in my development system but not on the live system.

Markdown users beware of the need of blank lines.

Sorry for the noise.